# Is there a way to export a Makefile from a Java Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, makefile, export, project

So I have this Java project made up of several classes, some external JAR files and an executable Java program. I would like to export the whole code and external JARS to an external directory and to produce a Makefile to build the program with all the dependencies. Is there an automated way to do it?

Thank you
Tunnuz

Comment: how are you building in eclipse. Did eclipse not generate an ant build for your project?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this too (but using ant, maven or eclipsebuild instead) to be used together with hudson/jenkins. Changing the eclipse project's build process is not an option, because it'd cost us too much (longer compiles, no hot code replace in debugger etc).

Comment: Unless explicitly setup, eclipse just uses the inbuilt tool called java builder. It does not generate maven or ant build scripts. See my answer on how to generate ant leveraging the java builder information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the question. Of course if you use an external build system like maven or ant, then we are decoupling the build process from the IDE. (But in some cases the IDE does integrate pretty closely with the build tool.)

But if you want to continue building using eclipse and to generate an ant file one fine day, then there is a tool for that. Its called [EBuild](http://ebuild.firefang.net/). It leverages all the classpath information that eclipse already has and builds an generic ant file out of it.

Comment: I was looking for something specifically targeted to make, but that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)?
If so this can be easily achieved with maven assembly.

If not, you can use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to bundle exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't actually known if Eclipse is using Maven or Ant, or whatever. I just created a Java Project.

Comment: However my Project Settings > Builders states "Java Builder".

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use anything else then what you tell it to use. I'm deducting that you haven't chosen maven the manage your dependencies so implementing that might be overkill for your needs (although I would recommend it). Ant however it quickly implemented and usable (since eclipse supports it OOTB). Basically you need to create an ant script (build.xml) which will compile, generate, ... your output. There are many ant tutorials on the wab (http://techtracer.com/2007/04/16/the-great-ant-tutorial-a-great-jump-start/).

Answer (score 0):

When you right-click your project in Eclipse, there is an option called "Export". It can create build.xml for ant for your project.

Comment: This does only create an ant build for for exporting but not for compiling the project.